# How to upload image from a URL to server using Angular-upload?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is the scenario, in my application, user logs in through their Facebook account, after Facebook authorization, I receive user's profile information, including a url to their profile picture, and on the next page I fill some parts of my form using the info I've received from Facebook Graph API.

My question is how can I upload user's profile picture as the main picture of their account in my application as I'm getting only a URL to that picture from Facebook API ?
Please note that I'm using AngularJS and a plugin to handle uploads, called [Angular Upload](https://github.com/leon/angular-upload).

I'm totally open to any suggestions or other workarounds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That would not be an upload in the classical sense (client has data, and uploads it to server), but rather a _download_ - your server _downloads_ the image from the URL. And that is rather trivial in PHP, and should be easy enough to research.

Comment: Thank you, yes thats true, but I'm trying not to ask backend developers to add or modify things on the server. Thats why I asked to see if there are any other workarounds for this problem . Thank you very much for the comment though.

Comment: Why not? That is a classical backend task IMHO.